# KStream deduplicate across multiple streams while keeping duplicates from within the same stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, duplicates, sequence, apache-kafka-streams

I have two Kafka streams.

The first, for example, `1,3,5,7,9` - no keys, but we have a (non-unique, given the rate of messages) timestamp.

The second, for example: `a:1augmented, c:3augmented, e:5augmented, g:7augmented, i:9augmented` - i.e. something has assigned a key to the values from the first topic, and (reversibly) altered the value. The timestamp won't necessarily match that of the first topic.

**However**, the second stream may have "duplicates" (when the value is changed back to match the first topic), but with different keys - e.g. `a:1aug, b:1augalt, c:3aug, ...`

The second stream may also be missing values from the first altogether, and also messages in the second stream may come out of sequence when compared to the first.

Which leaves us with the following example:

Stream 1: `1,3,5,7,9`
Stream 2: `a:1aug1, b:1aug2, i:9aug, g:7aug`

I want to reduce this to a single, third topic, as follows:

1. If the message exists only in the first stream, keep it
2. If the message exists in both streams, keep the key:value from the second stream
3. If the message exists only in the second stream, keep it
4. If the message exists multiple times in the second stream, keep all copies of the message from the second stream and none from the first.

Additionally, I want the sort order to match that of the first stream.

Using `.reduce` code works great for the first three conditions, but **how can I get the fourth condition to work, as it's no longer a pairwise comparison?**

My current code:

```java
// pull in the two input streams (raw and augmented)
KStream<String, String> rawInputStream = builder.stream(rawTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
KStream<String, String> augmentedInputStream = builder.stream(augTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

// map to a common key, so we can easily compare the messages. Store the original keys in the value also, so we can reuse them later.
// The raw input won't have any original key, so use a blank string.

KStream<String, CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin> mappedRawInputStream = rawInputStream
        .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(getCommonKeyFromRawInputStream(value)
                , new CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin(getValueFromRawInputStream(value),key == null ? "" : key, OriginStream.RAW)));

KStream<String, CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin> mappedAugmentedInputStream = augmentedInputStream
        .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(getCommonKeyFromAugmentedInputStream(value)
                , new CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin(value, key == null ? "" : key, OriginStream.AUGMENTED)));

// the outer join here will do a pairwise comparison across all records with a matching key, and just keep the records from the aggregated feed unless no agg value exists.
KStream<String, CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin> mergedStream 
            = mappedRawInputStream.outerJoin(mappedAugmentedInputStream, (value1,value2)-> {
                if (value2 == null) { // no augmented message
                    // log
                    return value1; }
                else if(value1 == null) {} // no raw message - log.
                return value2;  
    }
    // Add a time-based join window to allow for time differences and sequence issues
    ,JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(window, windowGrace));
    
// We'll potentially have duplicates now - e.g. one from each input stream, or two from one?; so group by key to bring together the records that share a key
KGroupedStream<String, CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin> groupedStream = mergedStream.groupByKey();

// ungroup the records again, reducing to remove duplicates. 
KStream<String, CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin> reducedStream
    = groupedStream.aggregate(LinkedHashSet<CustomMessageDetailsWithKeyAndOrigin>::new, (key, value, aggregate) ->  {
        if (value != null) {
            boolean added = aggregate.add(value); // won't add again if it's a duplicate
            if (!added){}
                // duplicate - log it.
        }
        return aggregate;
    }).toStream().flatMapValues(value->value);

// grab the original key from the key-value pair stored in the value field to use as the final key, and grab the value from the key-value pair to use as the final value
reducedStream.selectKey((key, value)->value.getOriginalKey())
    .mapValues((value)->value.getRawValue())
    .to(outputTopicName, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a .merge() followed by a custom processor to do this, which took the merged streams and processed them as required.